# Illustrator CS4 Gradient Following a Path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I'm trying to draw a power cable in illustrator, I want the cable to have one side dark and the other light with a gradient in the middle, because the cable has curved corners it won't work the usual way.

I have tried making an art brush with a gradient in it which definitely didn't give me the effect I was looking for.

Do you know anyway I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a gradient mesh. This tool allows you to create gradients that align themselves to the shape. This is sort of a manual tool and less points will work better.

If you shape is based on a square, it will work best. Click once in the centre with the Mesh Tool (U) and it will create a grid with different points. You can change the color property for any given point and then create your effect.

The tool can take some practice to implement correctly, but there is tons of "Gradient Mesh" tutorials online.